# Using access token to get additional user info from cognito?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt, amazon-cognito

I have have integrated a OAuth 2.0 Resource Server in my spring boot application using JWT and issuer URL as describe here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver I am integrating against AWS Cognito service and everything is working, however I am missing the information I want.

I am currently receiving the Access Token from the React front-end which does not contain any custom attributes for the user, only groups. As stated by the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html

Is there a way to get the custom attributes through the use of an access token, through a callback or something to Cognito?

Alternatively I could receive the ID token directly however after browsing around this does not seem like the best practice? I am pretty new to implementing OAuth 2.0 so I am not sure about all the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/oauth2/userInfo` endpoint will provide you information about the authenticated user.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/userinfo-endpoint.html

Comment: I had issue figuring out what the "custom domain" thing was, but it seems like I can just add it arbitrarily. I will give it a go tomorrow and mark the answer as accepted if it works. Thanks for confirming my suspicion.

Comment: Should we call `https://<your-user-pool-domain>/oauth2/userInfo` in our application as an async call? I thought we could use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` to get user info, but the context doesn't show user's email, first name etc.